# Finding a String in a folder path using RegEx

Tags: java, regex, string

I was wondering could you help me with the following issue: I am trying to use RegEx to find a string within a folder path.

For Example:

```
C:\Users\user\Documents\mystarfleet34academybadge
```

I would like to find just "fleet34academy" using a RegEx formula and output the result in java. I am new to using RegEx formulas so apologies for the constant questions. I have looked into using split but i could not get it to work

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to get the file ? Or just the String name ?

Comment: at the moment i am outputting the whole folder name as "mystarfleet34academybadge" but i would just like "fleet34academy" as the output

Comment: What makes "fleet34academy" part in it matching and the rest of it not? Could this be a more general rule or is it a singular case? (in which case you don't need regexes)

Comment: Are you looking for `'mystar(.*)badge'` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
String pattern = ".*mystar(.*)badge";
System.out.println("C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\mystarfleet34academybadge".replaceAll(pattern, "$1"));
```

Output:

```
fleet34academy
```

**Update**

```
String pattern = "^.*mystar(fleet[0-9]*academy)badge.*$";
System.out.println("C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\mystarfleet110academybadge".replaceAll(pattern, "$1"));
```

Output:

```
fleet110academy
```

Comment: but doesnt address question , the question asked is to find the string  and not the pattern , its not like ,the regex u supplied .*mystar(.*)badge  , will work for his folders , he meant that any folder name can be there in the path and to find that string in the path . the string will not always come in between mystarbadge or before mystar !

Comment: the reason i would like to use RegEx is that the number is in constant change but the string either side of the number will never change. EG: fleet34academy could be fleet86academy or fleet109academy.

Comment: +1, but I advise you to anchor the match at both ends (with `^.*` and `.*$`), to make absolutely certain it consumes the whole string.  And you should be able to replace that `(.*)` with something more specific, but we still don't know exactly which characters are permitted.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String str = "C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\mystarfleet34academybadge";
        System.out.println(str.contains("fleet34academy"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this snippet

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class New {
public static void main (String [] args) 
{
        String str="fleet34academy";

        String path="C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\mystarfleet34academybadge";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(str,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE|Pattern.LITERAL);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(path);
        while (m.find()) 
        {
            System.out.print("Start index: " + m.start());
            System.out.print(" End index: " + m.end());
            System.out.println(" Found: " + m.group());
        }



}
}
```

We have `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes in java.util.regex package .

In `Pattern` we use static method compile to feed in the properties like , what string to match and case sensitive or not etc , you can check the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) here.

In `Matcher` object we pass the String in which we have to find the pattern.

`m.find()` is called to find the pattern

Comment: You should be using Pattern flags with `|` instead of `+`.

Comment: oh yes that i have changed now , thanks for correction